# Extension and property FH (fixed point for actions on Hilbert spaces)

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Remind that a group $G$ has property FH if any $G$ action on a real Hilbert space has a fixed point. For $\sigma$-compact, locally compact groups this is equivalent to the celebrated Kazhdan's property (T).

Is property FH stable under extensions? i.e. if $$
is an extension of a group with property FH by a group with property FH, does it follow that $$ has property FH?

The similar statement concerning property (T) is true for locally compact groups, cf p. 69 of [Kazhdan's Property (T)](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf) by Bekka, de la Harpe, Valette, but I am really interested in property FH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by an "extension" of $N$ by $Q$ you mean a short exact sequence
$$
1\to N\to G\to Q\to 1.  
$$
Thus, $N$ can be regarded as a normal subgroup of $G$ and
$G/N\cong Q$ (as a topological group).

Suppose that we have a continuous isometric affine action of $G$ on a Hilbert space $H$. By the FH property of $N$, there exists a nonempty closed affine  subspace $A\subset H$, the fixed point set of $N$. Hence, $A$ is also isometric to a Hilbert space. Since $N$ is normal in $G$, the subspace $A$ is $G$-invariant. The group $Q$ then acts continuously and isometrically on $A$ (via the action of $G$, since $N$ acts trivially on $A$). Hence, by the property FH of $Q$, the group $Q$ has a fixed point $a\in A$. This point is fixed by $G$, of course.